# How to determine if true/false and then return a function

Tags: function, haskell, call, haskell-stack

I have truth tables for different logical operators;

```
truthtable a1
 | a1 == "mynot"   = [(p,q,r,s) | p <- [0,1], q <- [0,1], let r = mynot p, s <- ["mynot"]]
 | a1 == "myand"   = [(p,q,r,s) | p <- [0,1], q <- [0,1], let r = myand p q, s <- ["myand"]]
 | a1 == "myor"    = [(p,q,r,s) | p <- [0,1], q <- [0,1], let r = myor p q, s <- ["myor"]]
 | a1 == "myimply" = [(p,q,r,s) | p <- [0,1], q <- [0,1], let r = myimply p q, s <- ["myimply"]]
```

Now I have to make a function (`equiv`) that determines if two operators act the same and give a counter example if not. So for `equiv "myimply" "myimply"` it should determine that it is equivalent, but for `equiv "myimply" "myor"` it should call the function `counterEx` which gives a counterexample (that the operators are not the same).

Now I had this:

```
equiv a1 a2
 | truthtable a1 == truthtable a2 = True
 | otherwise = counterEx a1 a2

counterEx a1 a2 = truthtable a1 ++ truthtable a2
```

But of course, `equiv` has different outcomes and thus is not possible. However I don't really know how I can give a better counter example (than just give all possibilities and you would just look what is not the same). As well I don't really know how I can call the function `counterEx` if the truth tables are not equivalent but only determine that they are the same if the truth tables really are the same.

Comment: A much cleaner spelling of `truthtable` that has the exact same behavior would be `truthtable a1 = [(p, q, f p q, a1) | p <- [0,1], q <- [0,1]] where f = case a1 of "mynot" -> mynot; "myand" -> myand; "myor" -> myor; "myimply" -> myimply`. But if I were doing this, I think I would implement a very different behavior. For example, I'd want `data Operation = Not | And | Or | Imply` rather than using `String`s; I'd want `Bool` instead of integers; and I definitely wouldn't return the operator name in the result. (None of these address your question; they are style comments only.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic solution here is to use a custom return data type

```
type TTable = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]

data EquivResult
  = Equivalent
  | NotEquivalent TTable

equiv :: TTable -> TTable -> EquivResult
equiv a1 a2
 | truthtable a1 == truthtable a2 = Equivalent
 | otherwise                      = NotEquivalent (counterEx a1 a2)
```

One can also use `Maybe TTable` instead of defining a custom `EquivResult`, but it is less obvious that `Nothing` would mean "equivalent", and `Just _` would mean "_ is a counterexample".

```
equiv :: TTable -> TTable -> Maybe TTable
equiv a1 a2
 | truthtable a1 == truthtable a2 = Nothing
 | otherwise                      = Just (counterEx a1 a2)
```

By the way, why do you use the integers `0` and `1` for booleans? Why not `False` and `True` of type `Bool`. Using `Int` for booleans feels weird, and allows invalid values like `2`.

(As a general recommendation, I would suggest to start writing each function by declaring its type. Type signatures are very important to detect potential errors soon, and to help the compiler to produce better error messages.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think I can use your help, the reason why I'm working with integers instead of booleans is because that is a restriction within the assignment (for some reason).. So I would have to have one more function than I already have to call a result that can say more than just return the truth tables again right?

Comment: @JanvanDongen I don't understand what is the "one more function". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe it is not a function but what you say with data Equivresult ... Equivalent / TTable?

Comment: @JanvanDongen That is a new data type definition, with its associated constructors. You can either use that, or rely on the already-defined `Maybe` types.